# cleartool startview is not setting up view when i do setcs

Tags: bash, cleartool

I did a cleartool startview 
then a cleartool setcs on a file but when i do catcs view is not showing.
Need to run these on a bash tool so need to work on startview rather then setview.

Answer (score 1):

Try and do your setcs inside the view

```
cd /path/to/view/started
cleartool setcs /path/to/config/file
```

Then, still from inside the view, a cleartool catcs should show the right config spec.